# How to add and use "scripts" in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, script, planar-inductor

Please go easy on me as I am new to Altium and not much of a software geek - actually have no idea what a script is. Anyway - question is - how do I add a script to Altium Designer, and how do I execute/run it? Is it as simple as downloading these files and dragging them into the Altium interface?

I downloaded the files here: https://github.com/Altium-Designer-addons/scripts-libraries.
I then opened Altium and pressed File > Launch script, and navigated to the folder where the script I want to execute was held. This is the "planarTX" script.

The issue starts here. Once I have pressed the script to execute it.. nothing happens. Just goes back to the normal grey screen as if nothing has happened. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I am able to launch other scripts in Altium. For some reason, this particular script will not work...

[image: Blank page after pressing script file]

Answer (score 1):

When I run that script, a message appears at the bottom of the screen to "Choose Planar Tx center location".

Upon selecting that, a dialog box pops up with parameters:

[image]

The proper tracks are then generated.

[image]

I put all 4 files in one folder, and my version is AD20.1.12